# gitを使用するとnothing to commit, working tree cleanとなる

Tags: git, github

Macbookを買い替えて移行アシスタントを使ってGitとGitHubの設定をしようとしているのですが、うまくいきません。

まずgit addですが、以下のコマンドを実行しても問題なく動きます。

```
$ git add .
```

git statusを実行すると以下のようなメッセージが出ます。

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

次に、git commitをすると、普段は見なかったようなメッセージが表示されます。

```
$ git commit -m "test"
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

その後、以下のようにコードを実行してエラーは出ません。

```
$ git branch -M main
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/gncc/test.git
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

しかし、GitHubのリポジトリは更新されていません。
どうしたらGitHubのコードをアップデートできるようになるでしょうか？

PC買い替え前は問題なくpush出来ていたので、何かしらの設定の問題なのではないかと思うのですが・・・。

Comment: 「git add .」でコミット対象のファイルは準備されているか確認するためにgit statusと打ってみてください。対象のファイル一覧が見れるはずです

Comment: git status実行時に表示されるメッセージを追加しました。git commitの時と同じメッセージが表示されています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在のワーキングディレクトリを

```
mv test test.old
```

等とリネームし、バックアップとします。

次に、

```
git clone https://github.com/gncc/test.git
```

として`remote`が登録されたワーキングディレクトリを作ります

それができたら、そのワーキングディレクトリ（新しく作られた`test`ディレクトリ）のファイルを編集し、

```
git add .
git commit -m "メッセージ"
git push
```

したらどうなりますか？

Comment: こちらが求めていた挙動でした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

表示されたメッセージには必ず意味があるので、「何か表示された」で終わらずに「読んで理解しようとすること」をまずはおすすめします。

Git では大まかな流れとして以下のような手順で作業をします。

- ファイルを編集する
- `git add .` で編集したファイルをコミット対象に加える
- `git commit` でコミットを確定する
- 必要に応じて `git push` で GitHub 等のリモートリポジトリにも変更を反映する

---

一方、質問の環境では以下のメッセージが表示されたとのことですが、これはエラーメッセージではありません。

> ```
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
> ```

意訳を含めて翻訳すると

- コミットするべき変更は何もない
- ブランチはリポートリポジトリと既に同じ状態

結論として、恐らく **ファイルの編集を何もしていない** ため、`git add` から始まる一連のコマンドを実行しても変化が無い状態です。

**ファイルの編集を行ってから** 改めてコマンドを実行してください。

Comment: GitHubの最新版であったり、以前使用していたMacの段階からは変更・編集がある状態なのですが、こういった場合はどうやってGitHubや過去のMacのGitの情報を引き継いで更新すれば良いですか？